# Razorpay Refund

Tags: android, razorpay

on click of delete order i want to initiate a request of refund in razor pay but as soon as i click on delete order my app crashes and gives me this error.

i followed the steps as posted on this link 
https://razorpay.com/docs/api/refunds/

i used java normal refund.

please help me thanks.

Code:

```
if(payid!= null) {

        RazorpayClient razorpay = null;
        try {
            razorpay = new RazorpayClient("<api_key>", "<api_secret>");
        } catch (RazorpayException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            // Partial Refund
            JSONObject refundRequest = new JSONObject();
            refundRequest.put("amount", Amount); // Amount should be in paise
            Refund refund = razorpay.Payments.refund(payid, refundRequest); // this is line 341 of Order(Order.java:341)


        } catch (RazorpayException | JSONException e) {
            // Handle Exception
            Toast.makeText(Order.this, "Error With Refund: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        runn();

    }else {

        runn();
    }
```

error

```
2020-05-28 00:12:30.697 27573-27573/com.example.customerapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.customerapp, PID: 27573
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:214)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:144)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
    at com.razorpay.ApiUtils.processRequest(ApiUtils.java:159)
    at com.razorpay.ApiUtils.postRequest(ApiUtils.java:78)
    at com.razorpay.ApiClient.post(ApiClient.java:40)
    at com.razorpay.PaymentClient.post(PaymentClient.java:9)
    at com.razorpay.PaymentClient.refund(PaymentClient.java:39)
    at com.example.customerapp.Order.runn1(Order.java:341)
    at com.example.customerapp.Order.run8(Order.java:319)
    at com.example.customerapp.Order$2.onClick(Order.java:231)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:177)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7643)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Does your manifest file contains internet permission?

Comment: yes the net permission is granted      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: still getting this error

Comment: You should add this below lines after setcontent view:  setContentView(R.layout.mainLayout);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error 
`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at android.os.StrictMode` Usually occurs when the application attempts to perform a networking operation in the main thread.
To avoid this we have to call networking requests in other thread or Async Class.
**Consider the code below:**

```
 setContentView(R.layout.user_login);

 // put this below lines under setContentView in activity
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```